# i am getting an error as "void is an invalid type for the variable setAge"

Tags: java, encapsulation

```java
package practice;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;

public class Encpsltn {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        private int age;
        
        public void setAge(int ageStu){
                if(ageStu>0){
                    age=ageStu;
                }else{
                    age=0;
                }
                            
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't write a method inner another method body. The compiler recognized the setAge as an attribute(variable) not a method as your wish, and it can't be void.

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below

```
       public class Encpsltn {
        
            private int age;
            
            public void setAge(int ageStu){
                    if(ageStu>0){
                        age=ageStu;
                    }else{
                        age=0;
                    }
                                
                }
            
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
           // Create an object of Encpsltn 
         Encpsltn  obj = new Encpsltn ();
         obj.setAge(40);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a method inside another method. You can only call an already defined method inside another method. So the compiler assumes that `setAge` is a variable and not a method, which makes `void` an invalid data type. Because `void` cannot be used for variables.

Answer (score 0):

The method can not be defined inside another method. consider the following modification

```
public class Encpsltn {
private int age;
public void setAge(int ageStu){
                    if(ageStu>0){
                        age=ageStu;
                    }else{
                        age=0;
                    }
                                
                }
}
```

In You're the main method call `setAge()` method as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            
           // Create an object of Encpsltn 
         Encpsltn  encps= new Encpsltn ();
         encps.setAge(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
package practice;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;

public class Encpsltn {
    
    private int age;
        
    public void setAge(int ageStu){
        if(ageStu>0){
            age=ageStu;
        }else{
            age=0;
        }
                            
    }
     
}
public class Controller{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Encpsltn encpsltn = new Encpsltn();
    encpsltn.setAge(12);
    }
}
```